# Proximity to an arbitrary family and compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-spaces

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space

If we know that $A$ is not proximity to $A_\lambda$, $\forall\lambda\in\Lambda$. Is it necessarily true that $A$ is not proximity to $\cup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$? [[The proof]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJDAy.png)

I am asking about a theorem in our lecture notes that uses compactness (by turning arbitrary family to finite) to prove: In compact space, $A$ is near $B$ if and only if their closures intersect.

> Given a compact Hausdorff space, there is a unique proximity whose corresponding topology is the given topology: $A$ is near $B$ if and only if their closures intersect. More generally, proximities classify the compactifications of a completely regular Hausdorff space.

Comment: It's true for finite unions (by induction) using axiom 4 on the Wikipedia page. That the union is finite is from an application of compactness in said proof.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I understand that, but why did we need to turn the arbitrary union to a finite union in the first place?. Is it because proximity doesn't work with arbitrary union?

Comment: Yes because of that.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, is there an example of why it is not true for an arbitrary union?

Comment: $\sqrt 2 \delta \Bbb Q$ but for no $q\in \Bbb Q$ we have $\sqrt 2 \delta\{q\}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thank you.